# Prove $1 + \cos 2C - \cos 2A - \cos 2B = 4\sin A\sin B\cos C$ for $A$, $B$, $C$ the angles of a triangle

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Given that $A$,$B$ and $C$ are angles of a triangle, show that
$$1 + \cos 2C - \cos 2A - \cos 2B = 4\sin A\sin B\cos C$$

Answer (score 3):

We have: $1+\cos(2C) = 2\cos^2C, \cos(2A)+\cos(2B) = 2\cos(A+B)\cos(A-B)=-2\cos C\cos(A-B)\implies LHS = 2\cos C(\cos C+ \cos(A-B))= 2\cos C(\cos(A-B) - \cos(A+B)) = 2\cos C(-2\sin A\sin (-B)) = RHS$

Answer (score 3):

Note that
$$\cos u + \cos v = 2\cos((u + v)/2)\cos((u − v)/2)$$
and
$$\cos u - \cos v = -2\sin((u + v)/2)\sin((u − v)/2).$$
Hence
\begin{align*}
1 + \cos 2C - \cos 2A - \cos 2B&=1 + \cos (2\pi-2(A+B)) - 2\cos(A+B)\cos(A-B)\\
&=2\cos^2 (A+B) - 2\cos(A+B)\cos(A-B)\\
&=2\cos(A+B)(\cos(A+B)-\cos(A-B))\\
&=2(-\cos C)(-2\sin A\sin B)=4\sin A\sin B\cos C.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

Since $\cos2x=1-2\sin^2x$ and $a=2R\sin{A}$... and similar, it's just the law of cosines:
$$\sin^2C=\sin^2A+\sin^2B-2\sin{A}\sin{B}\cos{C}.$$
Done!

Answer (score 0):

Note:
$$RHS=4\sin A\sin B\cos C=$$
$$-4\sin A\sin B\cos (A+B)=$$
$$-4\sin A\sin B(\cos A \cos B-\sin A \sin B)=$$
$$-\sin 2A\sin2B+(1-\cos2A)(1-\cos2B)=$$
$$1-\cos2A-\cos2B+\cos(2A+2B)=$$
$$1-\cos2A-\cos2B+\cos2C=LHS.$$